# Objc - Is it possible to make subArrays from an NSArray based on key path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

There are a lot of similar questions on SO, but I cannot find an appropriate approach..

I have an array of route objects, For each object, I want to make an array of stations on that route.  I want to end up with X number of subarrays -- one subarray for each route/trip.

I've looked at `valueForKeyPath` and predicates, but I don't know how to make the subarrays -- each named with a trip identifier.

What's the best way to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: This question needs more clarification on how your data model is set up. You have an array of route objects and you want to make an array of stations on that route, ok; where do the stations come from? How are stations, routes and trips connected?

Comment: I have all the setup for the data -- I created a private API on my own hosted web-server. I suppose I could just bring the data for the route I'm dealing with. I hadn't thought of that. It will be easier for the little machines to handle, and it will make my project a bit more portable. So thanks for jogging my brain a bit.

Comment: *You* have all the setup, but we have no clue.  That was Alex's point.